# Godaddy domain redirect to my heroku server with URL changed

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, cloudflare

I paid to godaddy and made domain. 
onofflab.xyz

and forward it to my heroku app with url changed to 
https://myherokuappname.herokuapp.com

how can I maintain onofflab.xyz ?

someone told me to use cloudflare and should change nameserver on godaddy.

my configuration is as belows. 
it would be nice if you let me know where to add or modify.

this is heroku setting, it says failed

[image: this is heroku setting, it says failed]

cloudflare

[image: cloudflare]

below is godaddy dns management

[image: godaddy dns management]